# VBA Excel Reg-ex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I cant seem to figure out how to put this all into regex. I know there has got to be an easy way but i am stumped. I dont think you can do chaining with vba excel?  Any guidance would be awesome. Thanks!!

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

```
For Each Cell In Myrange
        strInput = LCase(Cell.value)
        strInput = Replace(strInput, " ", "-")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, ".", "-")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, ",", "-")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "'", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, ")", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "(", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "---", "-")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "--", "-")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "&reg;", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "&trade;", "")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, "%", "-percent")
        strInput = Replace(strInput, """", "-inch")

        Cells(Cell.Row, "F") = strInput
Next
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? You've dumped a bunch of string replace code, not explained a problem, there's absolutely no regular expression anywhere in your question... What's wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: You have various replacement strings, you can't merge it into 1 regex replace code.

Comment: Thanks, that was the question. I knew how to do it with replace strings, it’s the regex that I was trying to convert it to. Regex confuses me lol. For some reason I can’t seem to grasp it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

You require 4 regular expressions according to the information you've given.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for information on how to run regex in VBA

---

### Code

#### Expression 1

**Regex**

```
([ .,]|-{2,3})
```

**Replacement**

```
-
```

---

#### Expression 2

**Regex**

```
(['()]|&reg;|&trade;)
```

**Replacement**

---

#### Expression 3

**Regex**

```
(%)
```

**Replacement**

```
-percent
```

---

#### Expression 4

**Regex**

```
(")
```

**Replacement**

```
-inch
```

Comment: Thanks ;) this helps much appreciated